# What is the correct behavior of strtol?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I'm creating a wrapper function around `strtol()` for `int16_t`, and I ran across a problem: how to handle input such as `0x`? That is, is it valid as digit `0`, followed by non-digit `x`, or is it invalid because nothing follows `0x`?

tl;dr results: Windows rejects `0x` completely as described in the latter case, but Debian sees it as the digit `0`, followed by the non-digit character `x`, as explained in the former case.

**Implementations tested**<sup>1</sup>

- Windows

  - Visual C++ 2015 (henceforth MSVC)
  - MinGW-w64 GCC (5.2.0)
- Debian

For further comparison purposes, I included `sscanf()` with a format specification of `" %li"`, which is supposed to act like `strtol()` with `base==0`. Surprisingly, I ended up with two different results.

Code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *foo = "        0x";
    char *remainder;
    long n;
    int base = 0;

    n = strtol(foo, &remainder, base);
    printf("strtol(): ");
    if (*remainder == 'x')
        printf("OK\n");
    else {
        printf("NOMATCH\n");
        printf("  Remaining -- %s\n", remainder);
        printf("  errno: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    }

    errno = 0;

    base = sscanf(foo, " %li", &n);
    printf("sscanf(): ");
    if (base == 1)
        printf("OK\n");
    else {
        printf("NOMATCH\n");
        printf("  Returned: %s\n", base==0 ? "0" : "EOF");
        printf("  errno: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    }
}
```

Debian results:

```
strtol(): OK
sscanf(): OK
```

Windows results:

```
strtol(): NOMATCH
  Remaining --         0x
  errno: No error (0)
sscanf(): NOMATCH
  Returned: 0
  errno: No error (0)
```

There was no error in any case, yet the results differed. Initializing `base` to 16 instead of 0 made no difference at all, nor did removal of the leading blanks in the test string.

I honestly expected the result that I got on Debian: `0` is parsed as a valid value (whether `base` is 0 or 16), and `remainder` is set to point to `x` after seeing there were no valid hexadecimal values immediately following `x` (had there been any, the `0x` would be skipped whether `base` is 0 or 16).

So now I'm confused about the correct behavior in this situation. Is either of these behaviors in violation of the C standard? My interpretation of the relevant sections of the standard is that Debian is correct, but I'm really not certain.

---

<sup>1</sup> Cygwin exhibited the Windows behavior in the case of `strtol()` and the Debian behavior in the case of `sscanf()` for those who are interested. Since the behavior is of `%li` is supposed to match `strtol()` with `base==0`, I considered this a bug and ignored its results.

Comment: If you build under mingw-w64 with switch `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` then `sscanf` behaves properly, but not strtol. This flag indicates to use mingw-w64's own implementation of print/scanf, instead of redirecting to MS's C library.  I'm not aware of any flag to fix strtol though.

Comment: @M.M: But what is the proper `sscanf` behavior? musl apparently behaves like VS2015 (NOMATCH, return value: 0, errrno: 0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specification from 7.22.1.4 of C11:

> 3. If the value of base is zero, the expected form of the subject sequence is that of an integer constant as described in 6.4.4.1,
> 4. The subject sequence is defined as the longest initial subsequence of the input string, starting with the first non-white-space character, that is of the expected form

As described in 6.4.4.1, `0` is an integer constant, but `0x` is not. Therefore, the subject sequence is `0` for your input case.

So the correct behaviour is to return `0`, and `endptr` should be left pointing to the `x`.

Comment: 6.4.4.1 note 0x is a prefix for hex constant, I think strtol in this case take recognized that and treat 0x as a interpretation of base 16, it returns 0 because nothing followed the prefix.

Comment: @fluter, I don't buy that, but more relevantly, it does not match the observed behavior of `strtol()` in either glibc (Debian) or the MS C library, as presented in the question, nor the behavior of MS's `scanf()`.  (It is unclear whether it matches the behavior of Debian `scanf()`.)

Comment: @fluter, how so?  The post's `strtol()` specifies `base` 0, and its `scanf()` uses a `%i` field descriptor, which is expressly equivalent to `strtol()` with base 0.  These will recognize valid base-16 representations with a `0x` prefix, but they are not treating the input the way you suggest.

Comment: @fluter, I understand what you are suggesting, but again, *none* of the implementations are doing it that way.  The test code verifies that Debian `strtol()` recognizes the 'x' as the first character of the tail, not as part of the subject sequence, just as M.M. said.  It also shows Windows rejecting the input altogether.  In any case, "0x" by itself is not a valid integer literal per 6.4.4.1, so it would be incorrect to accept that as the subject sequence and convert it successfully.

Comment: @fluter  The grammar is given in 6.4.4.1 and it shows that a a prefix by itself is not an integer constant

Comment: `0` is a base 8 constant technically

Comment: @fluter because the return value is the value converted, which is `0` in this case

Comment: @fluter Yes, that case also returns `0`

Comment: Both of those cases return `0`. Is there a purpose to this endless series of questions?

Comment: @John Bollinger `scanf()` as mentioned in your comments,can differ from `sscanf()` as used in OP's post. `sscanf()` can _unget_ as many characters as it wants - it is only a string.  OTOH `scanf()` may only be able to `ungetc()` once.  So `scanf()` reads `0`, `x` and then a non-numeric, it may only be able to put back the non-numeric and not the `x`.  IOWs, bring in `scanf()`, rather than `sscanf()` complicates this issue.

Comment: @chux, you are right that I was sloppy about which variant of `scanf()` was the subject of the question, but I hope that can be forgiven on the basis of the standard's specification that "The `sscanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf`, except that input is obtained from a string (specified by the arguments) rather than from a stream" and that "the
`scanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf` with the argument `stdin` interposed before the arguments to `scanf`."  I don't see how that leaves room for these functions to differ among themselves as to how they convert equivalent input.

Comment: @John Bollinger The informative footnote C11 285 "fscanf pushes back at most one input character onto the input stream. Therefore, some sequences that are acceptable to strtod, strtol, etc., are unacceptable to fscanf." hints at this issue.  Further your citation's "except that input is obtained from a string ... rather than from a stream" implies processing is limited/varies per each of those 2 inputs.  2 differences, as I see it, 1) `fscanf() scanf()`  may have trouble _backing-up_ - `sscanf()` does not.  2) `sscanf()` _never_ scans a null character, `fscanf() scanf()` can scan such input.